# local-name() support in Collective.xdv

Tags: xpath, plone, xdv

I have a Plone 3.5 site and I am trying to embedded Simple Social's FB Like action for a content in a collective.xdv theme.  The FB Like function is embedded in an XML tag

```
<fb:like></fb:like>
```

I am trying to select its XPATH via

```
//*[local-name()="like"]
```

However, I do not see any output.  Is the above supported in collective.xdv?  Is there another way to select the fb:like tag in XPATH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The libxml2 HTMLParser used by lxml and thus xdv/diazo strips namespace prefixes, so you should be able to select it with "//like".

You will need to add some xslt code to fix up those tags, as they must be rendered as  in order to work:

```
<xsl:template match="activity|add-profile-tab|bookmark|comments|friendpile|like|like-box|live-stream|login-button|pronoun|recommendations|serverFbml|profile-pic|user-status">
  <xsl:element name="fb:{local-name()}" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

While xdv/diazo could be made to work with the XMLParser you would then need to ensure that you added an xmlns:fb="..." declaration to your document and that all your input was valid xhtml, which is difficult to ensure with browser based html editors.

Laurence

Comment: Thanks.  This works and I get the <fb:like>missing elements here</fb:like> tags with their attributes.  However, its child elements are missing.  I suspect its a different issue now and it may have something to do with the product's javascript requirement.  It works with the default theme.

Comment: Hi @h2o! Did you succeed getting the children? Would you accept the answer as correct and open up a new question?

Answer (score 0):

aiui, that's not how local-name works.  You need to match on a namespace-qualified tag, and then **local-name()** returns the unqualified name.  I believe `//*` is only returning a nodeset of tags in the default namespace.

Have you tried `//fb:like`? [I know, that's far too easy - and I think it's wrong - but then again, it **is** easy :-) ]

Comment: I don't know if it is correct because if I use it, collective.xdv breaks the theme.  If I select its parent node, I just get an empty <like></like> tag.