# xfbml support for diazo

Tags: facebook, plone, xfbml, diazo

I'm trying to use collective.simplesocial on my diazo-themed site (Plone 4.1), 
and notice the like button was broken.

The `<fb:like>` tag was transformed to `<like>` (the prefix is stripped). All other xfbml tags suffered the same problem.

I've tried to add `xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"` to html tag but it didn't work either.

Any idea to overcome this ?

Comment: See [old collective.xdv question][1] for a still valid answer to this problem.   


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578910/local-name-support-in-collective-xdv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for the plusone button (see comment for answer to your original question):

```
<xsl:template match="plusone">
  <xsl:element name="g:{local-name()}" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Chris ! 

Couldn't find the old question since I search the whole different keywords.